# Error when validating app archive

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, distribution, archive

When i try to archive my iOS app (for App Store submission), and then try to validate it in organiser, I get the following error message:

```
“PayAway” does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application.
```

I should mention that in my app I have a `QREncoder.xcodeproj` project imported. Could that cause this problem?

**scheme:**
[image]

Comment: Please show the contents of the your *archive* scheme.

Comment: Either screenshots or by typing out the contents.

Comment: You don't want to archive that test target, so turn that off for archiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the Build Settings for QREncoder.xcodeproj project and make sure that the "Skip Install" option under "Deployment" is set to YES.

Comment: i just did. u have to wait for 5 minutes before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This message means you have two executables in your bundle.  Could QREncoder be creating a executable and not a library?  Check the build settings in the QREncoder.xcodeproj.  Have a look through the generated bundle to see it gives any clues.